# Set value on series chart (Interop Excel)

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I use interop Excel to create chart in Excel file.

When i create the chart and set values ​​on series for the fist time, i do not have any problems.

It's when i make that for the second time that i have an error.

I have created a POC to reproduce the issues:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace POC_Excel
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application excel = null;
            try
            {
                excel = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please run Excel");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            try
            {
                LockUnlock(excel, true);

                var shapes = excel.ActiveSheet.Shapes;
                Console.WriteLine(" --- Create chart --- ");
                Excel.Shape shape = shapes.AddChart2(-1, Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered);

                Console.WriteLine(" --- 1st chart filling --- ");
                CreateSeries(shape);

                Console.WriteLine(" --- 2nde chart filling --- ");
                CreateSeries(shape);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error : " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                LockUnlock(excel, false);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        static void CreateSeries(Excel.Shape shape)
        {
            var seriesCollection = (Excel.SeriesCollection)shape.Chart.SeriesCollection();
            while (0 < seriesCollection.Count)
                seriesCollection.Item(1).Delete();

            var donnee1 = new object[] { 10, 20, 30 };
            var series = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
            Console.WriteLine("Add values to serie : " + donnee1.Select(v => v.ToString()).Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b));
            series.Values = donnee1;
            Console.WriteLine("Serie data : " + series.Formula);

            series.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlDoughnut;

            for (int i = 0; i < donnee1.Length; i++)
            {
                Excel.Point pt = series.Points(i + 1);
                Console.WriteLine("points : " + pt.Name);
            }
        }

        private static void LockUnlock(Excel.Application excel, bool isFiger)
        {
            excel.DisplayAlerts = !isFiger;
            excel.ScreenUpdating = !isFiger;
            excel.EnableEvents = !isFiger;
            excel.Interactive = !isFiger;
        }
    }
}
```

Could you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: "It's when i make that for the second time that i have an error." What error? COM exception? C# exception? Which line of code does it actually break on?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the capability to create 2 charts on one shape.  I'd suspect that's what's failing.  Try this ...

```
            Excel.Shape shape;

            shape = shapes.AddChart2(-1, Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered);
            Console.WriteLine(" --- 1st chart filling --- ");
            CreateSeries(shape);

            shape = shapes.AddChart2(-1, Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered);
            Console.WriteLine(" --- 2nde chart filling --- ");
            CreateSeries(shape);
```

Comment: I do that in POC to retroduce the problem.
It correspond to 2 differents update with differents data in my software.